# How can I uninstall all yum packages recently installed (oVirt Node / CentOS Minimal)

Tags: centos, virtualization, ovirt

I'm setting up oVirt (having no previous experience, so if you have a oVirt Node solution please tell me). When I install the ovirt-engine, it spits out a bunch of errors. I think this is more of an error with centOS/yum than anything. What happened is I ran: `yum install ovirt-engine`.

oVirt has this weird terminal hang issue, and I let it go for an hour (64gb ram, x5650 so no spec problems) and it was still hung. I reloaded, and now I can't install it. One of the errors is:

> Error: Package: json-smart-2.2-5.el7.noarch (ovirt-4.3-centos-ovirt43) Requires: jpackage-utils

and a bunch more like this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
yum install jpackage-utils ovirt-engine
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? Can you please edit the answer and give some more context?